# Why was my question on Windows Mobile closed ?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, site-definition

https://superuser.com/questions/246940/how-to-associate-m3u-files-with-windows-media-player

There are 101 Windows Mobile questions
https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile

and 178 WMP questions
https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-media-player

Comment: interesting... the first ten of those 101 windows mobile questions are closed. O_o wonder  if that should tell you something.

Comment: @KronoS no, the first questions are not closed. only my is closed. you have some bad default filter.

Comment: @IAdapter wut? http://i.imgur.com/qfWue.png

Comment: @Sathya: beautiful freehand circles. :)

Comment: @Sathya♦ wut? why you took picture after some of them were closed? its not fair! if I could go back in time I would take a pic too!

Comment: @IAdapter check on each of questions when it was closed.

Comment: @Sathya I don't need to, I know how many were open when I asked this question. However if you can do SQL select than please prove me wrong.

Comment: @IAdapter, no amount of discussion will make Windows Mobile on-topic here, so I suggest you drop it

Comment: @Ivo Flipse its not about WM, but about Sathya calling me a lier. I don't care, but I won't agree with her.

Comment: Start by checking out [Sathya's profile](http://meta.superuser.com/users/4377/sathya) so that you have the gender right; and then check when the questions were closed, **only one** of the questions covered by the screenshot has been closed since you asked this meta question. Thus only one has been open at the time you've posted this meta question.

Comment: @TomWij thats your opinion, I remember seeing a lot more question open with WM tag on. Abouyt Sathya, she doesn't care about people knowing her gender and so should not you. if she would care she would have a man's name. if theres a guy named sarah I bet he also has problem as being seen as a man on-line.

Comment: @IAdapter [Ad-hominem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attacks will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Sathya I don't understand, can you please explain what you mean? I'm not attacking you. I'm the one that is being attacked and called lier. About your nickname I just explained my point of view and I'm not willing to click on every person's name to get to know his gender - thats is just me, thats how I am. I got down-voted already, so I guess my opinion doesnt matter anyway.

Comment: @IAdapter: Sure, but then you would be an Interface Adapter? Can I perform the Turing Test? But seriously: It's not an opinion but it's a fact shown by the close dates of those questions, if you don't even care/try to check this yourself or [perform a query on a recent data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/q/93479/) then I don't see why we would lie? Feel free to wait for the next data dump and then confirm the close dates of the recent posts against the date of your post, you can already see this trend in the the most recent data dump shown in my previous link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) specifically mentions

> **and it is not about** …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except
>     insofar as they interface with your
>     computer**

[windows-mobile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile) questions deal with interfacing with a computer or were questions posted before the policies were changed, and will be dealt as-seen-on-basis.

Comment: I don't understand, so why other windows mobile questions are not closed?

Comment: @Iadapter `will be dealt on an as-seen-on-basis.`

Answer (score 6):

Other questions relate to using a Windows Mobile device in conjunction with a computer.

Answer (score 6):

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) in the not about section:

> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

Your question was solely about a mobile device, not how it syncs with other devices. Also, please don't point to a 101 Windows Mobile tagged questions and then claim that they are acceptable. Some of those are closed, and most are surprisingly about how to solve a problem syncing a Windows Mobile device with a computer.